# Check if directory contains only hidden files and no directories

Tags: bash

I'm trying to put a third check whether the directory contains only hidden files:

```
if [ ! "$(ls -A "$dir")" ]; then
  echo "Specified directory is empty"
  exit 1
elif [[ -z "$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f)" ]]; then
  echo "Specified directory contains only subdirectories and no files"
  exit 1
elif [[ -z "$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v '"$dir"/.*')" ]]; then
  echo "Specified directory contains only hidden files"
  exit 1
fi
```

The third check is what is not working. I tried getting a list of all files that don't match '.*' and checking if it's empty with -z, but it always tests true.
Do you have an idea?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: `grep -v '"$dir"/.*'` - do `'!' -name '.*'`. `if directory contains only hidden files and no directories` if a directory has only files, it has no directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Assuming you have the default values for `nullglob` etc,

```sh
files=(./*)
if [[ "${files[@]}" = './*' ]]; then
  echo "Specified directory is empty" >&2
  exit 1
fi
dirs=(./*/)
if [[ "${#dirs[@]}" = "${#files[@]}" ]]; then
  echo "Specified directory contains only subdirectories and no files" >&2
  exit 1
fi
hidden=(./.*)
if [[ "${#hidden[@]}" = "${#files[@]}" ]]; then
  echo "Specified directory contains only hidden files" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

There is an obvious race condition here, in that another process could add a new hidden file after `files` gets assigned, but before `hidden` gets assigned, for example.

The use of arrays makes this Bash-only; this should be obvious, but many beginners are confused about the [difference between `sh` and `bash`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

The immediate error in your attempt is that `'"$dir"/.*'` is in single quotes, and so gets interpreted verbatim (and even if you fixed the quoting, `.` in a regex matches any character, not a literal dot).  But more broadly, it seems excessive to use `find` when the shell itself can tell you what files you have.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the problem was the regex (and the qotes) indeed. I solved it like this: [[ -z "$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v ""$dir"/\..*")" ]]
I guess it's overkill, so I'll probably try your solution. What does >&2 do if I can ask?

Comment: Diagnostic messages should be displayed on standard error, not standard output. It makes less of a difference here, but it's good practice.